# boost::multiprecision and rocksdb::Slice string interaction c++

Tags: c++, boost, rocksdb

Hi can someone explain what is happening here to me?

Version:
librocksdb-dev/bionic,now 5.8.8-1 amd64 [installed]
librocksdb5.8/bionic,now 5.8.8-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
boost-cpp                 1.74.0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <rocksdb/db.h>

int main() {
    boost::multiprecision::checked_uint256_t check("115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935");
    std::string test = check.str();
    rocksdb::Slice dbkey = check.str();
    std::cout << check << std::endl;
    std::cout << dbkey.ToString() << std::endl;
    dbkey = test;
    std::cout << dbkey.ToString() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

output: 
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
        9237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639935
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet is undefined behavior:

```cpp
rocksdb::Slice dbkey = check.str();
/* ... */
std::cout << dbkey.ToString() << std::endl;
```

`rocksdb::Slice` is a "fat pointer" with a data pointer and a size, like C++20's `std::span` or C++17's `std::string_view`. It has no ownership of whatever you assign to it.

The result of `check.str()` is a temporary object, which means it gets destroyed at the end of the expression. After it was destroyed, the pointer stored in `dbkey` is no longer valid.

The way you generated the third line of output is the correct way to use `rocksdb::Slice` - one object to own the data, and a slice to view the data.